# Variance of Linear Regression Coefficients in Terms of VIF

Tags: multiple-regression, variance, variance-inflation-factor

I am trying to understand how to rewrite the variance of regression coefficients in terms of the variance inflation factor. To be specific If we have a regression with design matrix X, I know that we have:

$$
\widehat{\operatorname{var}}(\hat{\beta}_j) = s^2 (X^T X)^{-1}
$$

and my goal is to show that:

$$
\widehat{\operatorname{var}}(\hat{\beta}_j) = \frac{s^2}{(n-1)\widehat{\operatorname{var}}(X_j)}\cdot \frac{1}{1-R_j^2}
$$

where $R_j$ is the multiple r-squared for the regression between $X_j$ and the other predictors and $s^2$ is the residual standard error.

I have seen a proof on Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_inflation_factor#Definition) but would appreciate some help, either in understanding this proof or in providing a different proof or link to a reference to read.

Comment: Exactly! I tried tracking down the references from the Wikipedia article but never found any other proof than this one.

Comment: For the first equation, the variance of j-th regression coefficients should be a scalar, the j-th diagnoal of $$s^2(X^TX)^{-1}$$ As for the proof, treat $$X_j$$ as an dependent variable like $$Y$$ so that we get $$β_{∗j}$$ with the form in the wiki proof, which is the coefficient of regression of dependent variable $$X_j$$
over covariate(independent variable) $$X_{−j}$$, and then apply basic results for [Residual sum of squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residual_sum_of_squares)

Comment: For the last step multiplying $$n-1$$, we are considering unbiased sample variance.